# Wrong answer although the whole program logic seems to be working

Tags: c++

This is my solution to the problem [Codeforces-D2A-129 Cookies](http://codeforces.com/contest/129/problem/A). The program outputs a wrong answer at testcase 11, which is:

82

43 44 96 33 23 42 33 66 53 87 8 90 43 91 40 88 51 18 48 62 59 10 22 20 54 6 13 63 2 56 31 52 98 42 54 32 26 77 9 24 33 91 16 30 39 34 78 82 73 90 12 15 67 76 30 18 44 86 84 98 65 54 100 79 28 34 40 56 11 43 72 35 86 59 89 40 30 33 7 19 44 15

My program:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm> // for count() and sort()
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// function prototype
void erase_duplicates(vector<int> &, int, int);

int main()
{
    int num; // number of bags of cookies
    int total = 0; // total number of cookies
    int ways = 0; // number of ways Olga can take a bag of cookies
    int duplicates = 0; // number of duplicates of an element
    scanf("%i", &num); // getting number of bags of cookies

    vector<int> cookies(num); // number of cookies in the ith bag
    // getting number of cookies in each bag
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        scanf("%i", &cookies[i]);

    for(int j = 0; j < num; j++) // calculating total number of cookies
        total += cookies[j];

    // sorting the input
    sort(cookies.begin(), cookies.end());

    for(int k = 0; k < cookies.size(); k++)
    {
        if((total - cookies[k]) % 2 == 0)
        {
            // adding number of duplicates of the current element to the number of ways
            duplicates = count(cookies.begin(), cookies.end(), cookies[k]);
            ways += duplicates;
            // erasing the duplicates of that element
            erase_duplicates(cookies, cookies[k], k);
        }
    }
    //printing the possible number of ways
    printf("%i", ways);
    return 0;
}

// This function erases the duplicates of the element passed as the second argument.
// Parameters are: vector of integers, element, index of the element.
void erase_duplicates(vector<int> &cookies, int value, int k){
    for(int i = k; i < cookies.size(); i++){
        if(cookies[i] == value) // if it is a duplicate, remove it.
            cookies.erase(cookies.begin() + i);
    }
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: *What's wrong with my code?* -- Why not debug the code?  Debugging is part of the whole program writing process.  Also, to erase duplicates, you could simply use `std::unique`

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Okay thanks. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually no need of sorting.
The problem can be solved as - 
First sum all the array elements and find the number of even and odd elements.
Next if sum of array elements is odd then the bags having odd number of cookies can be stolen so answer would be the number of odd elements and if the sum is even then the answer is number of bags with even number of cookies.

Logic - Difference of two odd number is even 
        Difference of two even numbers is even

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

 using namespace std;
 int main()
{
    int n;
    vector<int> num;
    cin>>n;
    num.resize(n);
    int even=0,odd=0,sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>num[i];
        sum+=num[i];
        if(num[i]%2)
         odd++;
        else even++;
    }
   if(sum%2)
      cout<<odd<<endl;
   else cout<<even<<endl;
    return 0; 
 }
```